# How to do bitwise operations on HUGE binary columns

Tags: mysql, sql, binary, hex

I have a field in a mysql table which is called "palette". It acts like a rgb hex code, but instead of 3 colors, I have 12. so the length of this binary field is 24 if I don't count the 2 characters for "0x". The problem is I cant seem to be able to do bitwise operations on them, as if the program thought they are too big.

I want to do something around these lines (I'll make it smaller to make it easier to understand) : 0x123456 & 0x00FF00 in mysql and get 0x003400. But it doesnt seem to work at all as it is not the value I get.

I expect to get an exact value, but most of the time I get 0 (even when there is clearly a value) or the opposite of 0 (when the hex is only populated by "F"s).

Comment: 0x123456 & 0x00FF00 => 0x003400 is correct, isn't it? Are you saying this is wrong? Are you expecting 0x12FF56? That would be the bitwise or operator.

Comment: What I mean is that it is what I expect. But what I get can greatly vary on the value. I could get something like 0x000000 or 0xFFFFFF. My field looks likes this 0x123412341234123412341234 and there seems to be problems with bitwise operations on huge hex values.

Comment: How have you stored these long hex values? As TEXT or VARCHAR?

Comment: I tried A LOT of combinations. I tried them as varchar, binary(26), varbinary, bigint, decimal(30, 0). I also tried Casting them in each type but it always returns a broken value (I know it will return an int but once I convert it back to hex, it doesn't fit). Maybe the fact that it is stored in a field or it has 96 bits is the problem?

Comment: I'm running some tests now, I don't deal with these long hexes every day, one moment please.

Comment: It's okay, just you taking the time to even read this is enough :)

Comment: Well, I tried the `BINARY(12)` type, which seems most appropriate, and storing the colors is fine, but when I use `&` on them I end up with the same thing you do. Not what we want. Tried a lot of variants with `HEX()`, still not good. I'm sorry, for the moment I cannot work this out.

Comment: No worries, it seems to maybe be some kind of limitations. Thank you for you time :)

Comment: I do not really understand the issue. `SELECT 0x123456 & 0x00FF00` returns 13312 that is decimal representation of 0x003400. Sure, you can do `SELECT  HEX(0x123456 & 0x00FF00)` to get the '3400' if you like. Or, is the issue is long numbers?

Comment: The issue is when the numbers get super long. Short hex work fine but I cant shorten it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only issue is that you cannot work with long hex strings, you can implement your SP for this.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `bfunc`(
    `op` VARCHAR(3),
    `v1` VARCHAR(26) CHARSET latin1,
    `v2` VARCHAR(26) CHARSET latin1
)
RETURNS varchar(26) CHARSET latin1
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    SET @r = '';
    SET @r1 = REVERSE(TRIM(LEADING '0x' FROM v1));
    SET @l1 = LENGTH(@r1);

    SET @r2 = REVERSE(TRIM(LEADING '0x' FROM v2));
    SET @l2 = LENGTH(@r2);

    SET @l = IF(@l1 > @l2, @l1, @l2);
    SET @i = 1;
    WHILE @i < @l DO
        SET @c1 = SUBSTR(@r1, @i, 1);
        SET @c2 = SUBSTR(@r2, @i, 1);
        SET @b1 = CONV(IF(@c1 = '', 0, @c1), 16, 10);
        SET @b2 = CONV(IF(@c2 = '', 0, @c2), 16, 10);
        SET @b = '';
        CASE op
            WHEN 'AND' THEN SET @b = @b1 & @b2;
            WHEN 'OR'  THEN SET @b = @b1 | @b2;
            WHEN 'XOR' THEN SET @b = @b1 ^ @b2;
        END CASE;

        SET @r = CONCAT(@r, HEX(@b));

        SET @i = @i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN REVERSE(@r);
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

```
SELECT bfunc('AND', '0x123456000000000000000000', '0x00FF00000000000000000000')
```

=>
03400000000000000000000

Sure, for production environment you will need to optimize it and do the bitwise math not on 'per char' basis but for example on 'per 8 chars'

Comment: Okay, so, is your solution faster or is the "hack" I just made more optimal? What I did is make it a varchar without the "0x" and I do a substring. Will it be slower on large amounts of rows?

Comment: I think your 'native' solution will be faster.